# windows forms file browser with 'any' data source

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I need some sort of windows forms control which will basically have to look (almost) exactly like the file browser but will be fed by a webservice.
I've built a webservice which can be used as a file browser, but I'd like it to be browsable by a 'file browser'-like control. I'd also like to be able to use is as a local file browser.

I'd like to have some advice on what would be the best aproach. I've been looking at [FileBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) but I haven't been able to inherit from it in a way I can compile yet.

Could someone provide some advice on how to approach this wish?
If someone knows about something similar that already exists, I'd also like to know that. (I haven't been able to find something similar)

Thank you

**Edit 1:**
I noticed that I miss a couple of things. I'd like the items to show up including icons. The icons might come from a different source. So I think the best would be to create a control for the items and make sure that the dialog accepts an array of that control as a data source.

**Edit 2:**
I've attached an image of what I'd like it to look like.
Based on the answers in the comment, it looks like I can do 2 + 3 with a ListView.
4 can be done with basic input controls.
I'm not sure what to do 1 with though. The most important part of 1 is the address bar. I want to make this read only but with clickable folders. Would I have to make a read-only textfield with buttons on top of it with transparent backgrounds? Or is that not an option?

[image]

Comment: Even simpler is a listview with the good old ".." entry for the parent folder. :)

Comment: The service currently returns an array of a custom struct. The struct holds the file/folder name of the item, the folder it is in (base folder) and stuff like permission variables. Accept rate?

Comment: @Davio i thought treeview because of the visual "nesting" effect for subfolders you get for free, but listbox is good too (for a nice total commander-like app)

Comment: Well yes, @alex, I've used a Treeview like this before, but then you have to do a lot of work at once. If you begin with a simple listview, you can just load one folder at a time.

Comment: @GregBair, Thanks I didn't notice that :) The TreeView is not really what I'm looking for. I'd really like it to look like the default openfiledialog/savefiledialog as it looks in windows 7.

Comment: I'm looking at the listview atm, I'll report my thoughts about it here when I know more about it and tried it, thanks

Comment: @MrSoundless after seeing the screenshots, I definitely agree with the ListView suggestion. It's actually pretty simple if you already have all the data you need (and you do, since you already have built the service). you just have to put together a viewmodel class for the listview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with an open source (LGPL) third party component, try this one: http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

[image]

Comment: As long as it doesn't have the clickable folders in the address bar, I think it's easier to built one from 'scratch'. Aside of that, it looks like the project is abandoned for 2 years now.. Thanks for the effort.